# Import XML data into C# Form & datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

Im having issue with saving Form data back into xml file from which i initially import some of the data.

for simplicity, lets say i have customer data, First name and Last name whcih i am importing from a file into datagridview. Here i have extra form fileds placed where i add details like Address, Phone number and Customer picture.

Once i have added this data i need to save my initial file with these 3 extra fields in xml.  that can be read again, if required.

Im novice and stuck on how to do this, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
newel=xmlDoc.createElement("edition");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[0];
x.appendChild(newel);
```

You can append new elements to your XML DOM.
Here is more info : http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_add.asp

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't post any code snippet, am assuming you don't have any structure, i've created an `Employee` class as `Data Model`

```
//Data Model
class Employee
{
    string _firstName;
    string _lastName;
    string _address;
    string _phoneNumber;
    string _picturePath;

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PicturePath { get; set; }
}

private static void InitializeDataTableFromXML(ref DataTable dataTable)
{
        // you can read your new details from Contorls's value from your Form, then form a Enumerable collection like List<Employee> employees, and create a DataTable as folllows
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        // form your collection
        employees.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "your First Name from XML File", LastName = "your Last Name from XML File or from Form Control", Address = "your new Address from Form Control or from Form Control", PhoneNumber = "your new Phone Number from Form Control", PicturePath = "your new Picture path from Form Control" });
        .
        .
        ,
        employees.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "your First Name from XML File", LastName = "your Last Name from XML File or from Form Control", Address = "your new Address from Form Control or from Form Control", PhoneNumber = "your new Phone Number from Form Control", PicturePath = "your new Picture path from Form Control" });

        DataRow dataRow;
        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow["FirstName"] = employee.FirstName;
            dataRow["LastName"] = employee.LastName;
            dataRow["Address"] = employee.Address;
            dataRow["PhoneNumber"] = employee.PhoneNumber;
            dataRow["PicturePath"] = employee.PicturePath;
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
}

private static void ReadOverriteXML(string xmlFilePath, DataTable dtNewXMLData)
{
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(xmlFilePath))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");

            foreach (DataRow row in dtNewXMLData.Rows)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Employee");
                writer.WriteElementString("FirstName", row["FirstName"].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("LastName", row["LastName"].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("Address", row["Address"].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("PhoneNumber", row["PhoneNumber"].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("PicturePath", row["PicturePath"].ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
}    

// call to the methods
DataTable dtXML = GetDatTable();
InitializeDataTableFromXML(ref dtXML);
ReadOverriteXML("Employee.xml", dtXML);
```